# Write down latex equation in github page

Tags: markdown, git

I have a github page. I have a school project that I want to display in my Github page. There are several equations and figures related to this project. **How could I write down this equation and draw figures in my Github page**. I know how to write down equations and draw figures in **.tex** file.

Comment: Are you talking about the README of your github page?

Comment: Yes. The page with extension .md.

Comment: Math on Github: [Rendering math equations](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/897#issuecomment-231591884)

Comment: gitlab supports equations in markdown files. You could move your project there.

Comment: You can use my browser extension [xhub](https://github.com/nschloe/xhub) for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

GitHub doesn't support equations in a readme file; you're best embedding an equation using a service such as [iTeX2img](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor).

See further [How to show math equations in general github's markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256433/how-to-show-math-equations-in-general-githubs-markdownnot-githubs-blog).

Comment: Can you explain how could I use the link iTeX2img? When I write something in the mentioned link it has 3 options Web Page, Forum, Twitter, Google Docs. Which one work. When I copy one of this link in the github .md page it show the link url as plain text. No equation.

Comment: Look further down for the Web page embed code, which you can add to your file.

Comment: Under the embed code there is 3 option Webpage, Forum, twitter and google doc. Which one is appropriate?

Comment: As I noted, you want the 'Web Page' option.

Comment: Web page option not working.